# Configuring MSAD in RHEL

Tags: linux, ldap, active-directory

We are trying to configure MSAD in our LINUX VM(RHEL).So that users can login with there accounts directly to the LINUX VM(RHEL) instead of using service accounts.Can someone help  me out here ?

Thanks,

Comment: By MSAD, do you mean an MS AD?

Comment: Microsoft Active Directory

Comment: have you tried using `libnss-ldap` and `libpam-ldap`?   AD is, or can configured to be, an LDAP server.  there are even, IIRC, unix extensions for AD to help support account details needed by unix (such as uid and gid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of rhel?

For 6.x, the easiest tools are [pbis](http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True), [centrify](http://www.centrify.com/products/server-suite/system-catalog/red-hat-enterprise-linux/). They do all the discovery and configuration. You only need to provide and account+password that can add/remove machines in AD.

For 7.x, the best tool is [realmd](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/realmd/)

## Edit:

We are using pbis here for both 6.x and 7.x:

- go [here](http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True) and download [pbis-open-8.3.0.3287.linux.x86_64.rpm.sh](http://download.beyondtrust.com/PBISO/8.3/pbis-open-8.3.0.3287.linux.x86_64.rpm.sh) (or whatever is the latest version)
- extract the rpm files (the files will go to pbis-open-8.3.0.3287.linux.x86_64.rpm/packages/):

  ```
   bash ./pbis-open-8.3.0.3287.linux.x86_64.rpm.sh --noexec
  ```
- install pbis-open and pbis-open-upgrade rpms from above dir
- start the service:

  ```
   service lwsmd start
  ```
- add machine to ad:

  ```
   /opt/pbis/bin/domainjoin-cli join domain.com AD_user AD_pass
  ```
- If you want to remove machine from ad:

  ```
   /opt/pbis/bin/domainjoin-cli leave --multiple domain.com AD_user AD_pass
  ```

Comment: Thanks cristi,We are on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago).Am very much new to this,Can you please give me the steps how to do that.

Comment: pbis  is a open source ?

Comment: They have 2 versions: pbis open , which is open source (http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/licensing/) and pbis enterprise, for which I don't know the license

Comment: Thanks Cristi for prompt response,I will try this and update you the same

Comment: Tried Sir and below the error am getting

Comment: Error: DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET [code 0x0000251e]

A bad packet was received from a DNS server. Potentially the requested address does not exist.

Comment: This looks like a network error? Output of cat /etc/hosts and cat /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the native tools.   This is a weak original answer but this is one of the best documents I've seen regarding your exact problem.  It's somewhat laborious but well worth the read/effort.

[[1]: https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rhel-ad-integration-deployment-guidelines-v1.5.pdf](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rhel-ad-integration-deployment-guidelines-v1.5.pdf)